# Custom loading indicator doesn't show up in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I've designed a custom animation as my activity indicator:

```
class LoadingIndicator: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

}

func startLoadingIndicator() {
    //Animation Logic
}

func stopLoadingIndicator() {
    //Stop and hide animation
}
}
```

This class works as a storyboard custom class inside my launch view controller and shows the animation correctly.

Now I want to add the same class on my submit buttons to show the animation while waiting for the network response.

I've added these functions to my SubmitButton class:

```
class SubmitButton: UIButton {

var originalButtonText: String?
var loadingIndicator: LoadingIndicator!

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    ...
}


...

//I call this method in my view controller:

func showLoading() {
    originalButtonText = self.titleLabel?.text
    self.setTitle("", for: .normal)

    if (loadingIndicator == nil) {
        loadingIndicator = initLoadingIndicator()
    }

    showAnimating()
}

func hideLoading() {
    ...
}

private func initLoadingIndicator() -> LoadingIndicator {
    let loadingIndicator = LoadingIndicator()
    return loadingIndicator
}

private func showAnimating() {
    loadingIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    centerLoadingIndicatorInButton()
    loadingIndicator.startLoadingIndicator()
}

private func centerLoadingIndicatorInButton() {
    let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: loadingIndicator, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(xCenterConstraint)

    let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: loadingIndicator, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.addConstraint(yCenterConstraint)
}
}
```

But I can't see my animation. I've tried adding an UIActivityIndicatorView and a simple rectangle view, both of them appeared on my button. So there should a problem with the LoadingIndicator class or how I initialize it. But I can't find what. I couldn't put the LoadingIndicator view inside the button even without the animation. I tried giving it a background color and it's nowhere. What can I try?

**Solution**

There were two problems:

1. Because I've used `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, the width and height anchors were zero and I should have defined them as constraints:

   let constraints = [
           loadingIndicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34),
           loadingIndicator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10),
           loadingIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
           loadingIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
       ]

   ```
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
   ```
2. I've called the animating method in `viewDidLoad`, I tried `viewWillAppear` and now I can see the animation finally!

Comment: Your code seems to look fine, but for help you can refer this - [ProgressButton](https://github.com/udbhateja/progressButton)

Comment: Use Xcode's View Debugging feature to capture the view hierarchy while running.  That will show you what views you have both visually and as a list of objects.  Check whether your object is in the list.  If it is, look for a 0 dimension or an off-screen location.

Comment: It might help if you showed us what's in your code for `startLoadingIndicator` method.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks, I didn't know about this feature, it helped me find one of the problems. because I've used `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, my view's size was zero.

Comment: @Pierce Because it worked somewhere else, I thought it should be irrelevant. Thanks for your comment.